# require.js require inside a require

Tags: requirejs

Why do we want to have another require structure inside a require structure?

like

```
require([mod1,mod2], function(m1, m2){

  require([mod3], function(m3){
    // and then will use m1 and m2 here as well
  })
})
```

Why can't we just have one require structure? I want to understand the motivation between this setup.

Answer (score 4):

Nested require isn't mandatory, and can easily be avoided if this don't fit your style.

Although, this can be useful to load submodules or conditional modules (like a polyfill).

In a more personal experience, I often use nested require inside my `router` controller in order to load certain page view when they're requested. This allow me to request only the dependencies of my `router` without loading the entire page collection of an app.

I also often find myself using nested require to manage some `i18n` aspect of some apps by loading conditional locale.

Last thing, I'd just remember that modules should be defined using `define`, not `require`. `require` function is really used to arbitrary load scripts if needed (and can be use once to bootstrap your app). So in most of the real use case, you'll have some nested `require` inside a `define` module definition.

Hope this help!

Comment: i have a question for that. i have in my router('backbone') nested require. using require. it works good. but when i use grunt requirejs task. it simply doesnt find the nested one. any ideas?